# Keep hidden part of the template from being executed

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following code:

```
<div ng-show="false">
  <div ng-controller="expensive"></div>
</div>
<script>
var expensive = function() {
  console.log('expensive');
};
</script>
```

I would like the expensive controller to *not* be invoked, because it's expensive (in real life, it triggers a bunch of I/O) and has no useful effect.  It would like it to be invoked only when the show expression (or its equivalent) is true.

Incidentally, the following works (and illustrates my point), but it's god-awful ugly:

```
<button ng-click="visib=!visib">display</button>
<div ng-repeat="v in (visib && [1] || [])">
  <div ng-controller="expensive"></div>
</div>
<script>
var expensive = function() {
  console.log('expensive');
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ngSwitch` which places elements in the dom when the switch condition is evaluated.

```
<div ng-app ng-switch on="causeIt">
    <button ng-click="causeIt = true">Make Expensive</button>    
    <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-controller="expensive"></div>
</div>
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Ys4en/)**

Comment: Open palm.  Apply to face liberally as needed.

Comment: I found out about `ngIf`.  Keep your upvote, but I have to take the check-mark away from you.

Comment: Actually, answer from @mark is more correct than yours since he's providing a solution that works in latest stable release (v1.0.7), and your solution (with `ng-if`) requires unstable version of AngularJS.

Comment: That would be an important point.  Do you have a source for the schedule where these things become available?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer turns out to be [ngIf](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf).

> The ngIf directive removes and recreates a portion of the DOM tree